# Finding the basic reproduction number of a particular model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, applications

I have been reading a paper about a host-parasites models and for the model:

$$\begin{array}{rll}
\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}}&=\lambda -dx -\beta v x  & \text{Susceptible host} \\
\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dt}}&= \beta v x -(a+d)y      & \text{Infected host} \\
\displaystyle{\frac{dv}{dt}}&= cy-uv                  & \text{Free parasites} \\
\end{array}$$

Where $\lambda$ is rate of susceptible host are born, die at rate $dx$, and infected at rate $\beta vx$. Infected host are assumed to die at rate $(a+d)y$. The free parasites are released from infected hosts at rate $cy$ and die at rate $uv$.

For this model, the basic reproduction number according with the paper is:
$$R_0=\frac{\lambda \beta c}{d(a+d)u}$$

I read another article about how to find $R_0$ (spectral radius of a special matrix), but does not apply to this case.

I understand that $R_0$ greater than $1$ is required for successful invasion of parasites, but not know how to determine in this case.

Can someone explain in detail how to determine $R_0$ in this case?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: you can find the paper [here](http://www.tb1.ethz.ch/Publications/PDFpapers/Regoes_PROCEEDINGS_OF_THE_ROYAL_SOCIETY_OF_LONDON_SERIES_B-BIOLOGICAL_SCIENCES_2002_269_271-279.pdf), in the last two paragraphs of Section 2 explains a little about R, but not on how to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R_0$ in this context is an average number of cells, which were infected by 1 infectious cells put in a naive (fully susceptible) population.

The rate at which infected cells are produced is given by
$$
\frac{\beta c x}{u}.
$$
If all the population susceptible then 
$$
x=\frac{\lambda}{d}.
$$
Finally, since the average lifespan of infected cell is 
$$
\frac{1}{a+d},
$$
we get the desired answer
$$
R_0=\frac{\beta c}{u}\cdot \frac{\lambda}{d}\cdot \frac{1}{a+d}.
$$

Comment: I didn't get how did you find the rate at which infected cells are produced. Can you please enlighten me? That would be great.