# How do I calculate the equilibria, rate of production of infected cells, average lifespan of infected cells and basic reproduction number?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology, population-dynamics, epidemiology

I have the following infection system:

$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda-d\cdot x(t)-\beta\cdot v(t)\cdot x(t)
$ $\rightarrow$ Susceptible cells

$
\frac{dy}{dt}=\beta\cdot v(t)\cdot x(t)-(a+d)\cdot y(t)
$ $\rightarrow$ Infected cells

$
\frac{dv}{dt}=c\cdot y(t)-u\cdot v(t)
$ $\rightarrow$ Free parasites

**Q1**: How exactly do I calculate the possible equilibria? I know that the infection-free equilibrium is calculated by setting $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$, $y(t)=0$ and $v(t)=0$, but how exactly do I calculate other possible equilibria?

**Q2**: In many articles, they mention that the rate at which infected cells are produced in this particular system in $\frac{\beta\cdot c\cdot x(t)}{u}$, but how exactly do I get to that expression? In general, what's the logical thinking that is used to calculate get to this expression?

**Q3**: How exactly do I get to the expression that represents the average lifespan of an infected cell? Many articles mention that for this system, it's $\frac{1}{a+d}$.

**Q4**: And finally, based on all the questions above, how do I calculate the basice reproduction number for the system?

Note: I would really appreaciate it if you could provide me with an introductory reference where these calculations are detailed and well-explained.

Comment: Hi, you are requested to ask only one question (instead of four) from your next post onwards. This helps make posts more focused and to the point for potential answerers.

Comment: All these questions are related to the same system of equations. I don't see the reason to create 4 different posts.

Comment: Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785245/finding-the-basic-reproduction-number-of-a-particular-model?rq=1

Comment: I had already seen that post, but they don't explain how we get to those expressions. They simply give the final expressions.

Answer (score 1):

*Partial answer*

To answer **Q1**, equilibria of a dynamical system are generally found by setting all derivatives to $0$, so you get the system

$$0=\lambda-dx-\beta vx$$
$$0=\beta vx-(a+d)y$$
$$0=cy-uv$$

You can solve this system to find $v=y=0,\ x=\lambda/d$, or $x=\frac{u(a+d)}{c\beta},\ v=\frac{\lambda c}{u(a+d)}-\frac d\beta,\ y=\frac{\lambda}{a+d}-\frac{du}{c\beta}$. No other equilibria exist as far as I can tell.

You might then be interested in the stability of these equilibria, which can be calculated by linearising the system around this point. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Non-linear_autonomous_systems)